# Decrypt in Golang what was encrypted in Java (without iv)

Tags: java, go, encryption

Wenn I try to decrypt a string, encrypted in Java I get an error: *"cipher: message authentication failed"*.

Does java *inputOffset* from *AESCipher.engineDoFinal(byte[] input, int inputOffset, int inputLen)* meens the same as the Go *nonceSize* in my code?

And is "*NewGCMWithNonceSize*" a right one decoder for my issue?

Thanks for help.
**Working solution:**

**JAVA**

```
public static String encryptGCM(String data) throws CryptException {
    try {
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        byte[] iv = new byte[12];
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        log.trace("IV: {}", Arrays.toString(iv));
        Key key = generateGcmKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        log.trace("encrypted: {}", Arrays.toString(cipherText));
        byte[] result = new byte[cipherText.length + iv.length];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.length);
        System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, result, iv.length, cipherText.length);
        log.trace("Not encoded result: {}", Arrays.toString(result));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Failure occured while encrypt text value!", ex);
        throw new CryptException(data, ex);
    }
}

private static Key generateGcmKey() throws CryptException {
    try {
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), 0, KEY.getBytes().length, ALGO);
        log.trace("Encoded key: {}", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalKey.getEncoded()));
        return originalKey;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Failure occured while generate key!", ex);
        throw new CryptException("Failure occured while generate key!", ex);
    }
}
```

**GO**

```
func decode(data string) (string, error) {
  ciphertext, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(data)
  key, _ := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(decodeKey)
  c, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }

  gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }

   nonceSize := 12
   if len(ciphertext) < nonceSize {
     return  "", errors.New("ciphertext too short")
   }

   nonce, ciphertext := ciphertext[:nonceSize], ciphertext[nonceSize:]

   result, err := gcm.Open(nil, nonce, ciphertext, nil)
   if err != nil {
     return "", err
   }
   return string(result), nil
 }
```

Comment: The two code excerpts aren't even remotely similar.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how you encrypt the text? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, wrong java function, copy&paste... I have edit my post.

Comment: Still uses the default encryption mode (ECB) in Java and GCM in Go. Use GCM on both code fragments. Do **not** use the code from the first answer as it uses the **insecure** ECB mode for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As noted in the comments to the question the follwing code is not secure since it uses the [ECB mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_(ECB)) for encryption which should not be considered secure.**

---

The problem is that GCM expects the underlying encrypted data to contain authentification information.
This information is not supplied by your Java implementation.

Instead you can use your created AES cipher directly to loop over the blocks of the message.
This could look like this:

```
func decode(data string) (string, error) {
    ciphertext, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(data)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    c, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(DECODE_KEY))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    result := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
    for i := 0; i < len(ciphertext); i += aes.BlockSize {
        c.Decrypt(result[i:], ciphertext[i:])
    }

    return string(result), nil
}
```

Each call to `c.Decrypt` decrypts one block from `ciphertext` into `result` as noted in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#Block).
Also notice that the increment between loop iterations is the block size of the AES cipher.

The last block may contain padding, which you still need to remove.

Comment: But in this case len(encryptedString)%16 must be 0? 

 String s = encrypt("1234567890ABCDE");
s.length() is 24. 

I got "input not full block" Exception in go

Comment: Ok, block size is depend to key length, i my case  24 bytes.
But it still not works, decoded string is not utf8 :(

decode() = �[�������1�(9�        , want 1234567890ABCDE

Comment: Your encryption function in Java encodes the result using base64. I didn't account for that in the Golang decryption function. I edited my answer to decode the data before decrypting it.

Comment: Downvoted for ECB mode. Disclaimer or not, you shouldn't be distributing insecure code on the internet.  OP wanted to use GCM mode for a reason.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I didn't see OP asking for using GCM. But you're right this answer is not only insecure but also no longer answers the question.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. In a lot of cases, it's important to show 'bad' implementations because a lot of real life code is not that great.Doing this not only allowed me to progress with my work as it did make me report the flaw on the Java side, which can now be fixed. Thanks.